# Using google docs viewer to load PDF in webview. Not scrolling in 7.0

Tags: javascript, android, pdf, webview

I've been having this very weird behaviour when using the WebView, to load up google docs viewer, and display a PDF from another URL.

Basically, it's working properly in Android 6.0, but when I try it on 7.0, it just won't scroll. I tried loading other web pages and they scroll just fine, even tried supplying the docs viewer with different pdfs, only to get the same result.

Here's my layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- Irrelevant items cut to make this shorter... -->

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/WebView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

And here's my code:

```
final WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();

settings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
settings.setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR2) {
    settings.setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH);
}

webView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient() {
    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onConsoleMessage(ConsoleMessage consoleMessage) {
        Log.w(String.format("onConsoleMessage: %s -- From line %s of %s", consoleMessage.message(), consoleMessage.lineNumber(),
                consoleMessage.sourceId()));
        return true;
    }
});

webView.loadUrl("https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=" + webViewUrl);
```

I have reason to believe this is being caused by JavaScript errors, since onConsoleMessage is logging messages like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'kind' of undefined -- From line 554 of..." (4 of them with different properties).

Thanks in advance, if someone could help me out solving this issue.

Comment: Use [some other option for viewing PDFs](https://commonsware.com/blog/2017/01/04/options-viewing-pdfs.html).

Comment: I'm aware of the other alternatives, but it's not up to me to decide that. Using ACTION_VIEW is pretty much our plan B, I think, in the lack of a solution for this.

Comment: We ended up using [AndroidPdfViewer](https://github.com/barteksc/AndroidPdfViewer). It suits our needs and works very well.